# inno setup identifier expected

Tags: deployment, dependencies, inno-setup

So I am getting an identifier expected error in Inno Setup Script IDE and I was wondering how to fix it. This is related to install a required dependency of the program if it does not exist. The Code is below:

```
[code]
function FrameworkIsNotInstalled: Boolean; 
begin
  Result := not RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v4.0');
end;
procedure InstallFramework;
var
  StatusText: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  StatusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing .NET framework...';
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
  try
    if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe'), '/p /noreboot', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
       MsgBox('.NET installation failed with code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) + '.',
         mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  finally
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusText;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal;
  end;
function isADBinstalled: Boolean; //error occurs on this line
begin
  Result := not DirExists(ExpandConstant '{sd}\adb');
procedure installadb
var
StatusText: string;
begin
StatusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing ADB this shouldnt be long...';
WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
  try
    if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\adb-setup-1.4.2.exe'), '/p /noreboot', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
       MsgBox('ADB Install failed with code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) + '.',
         mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  finally
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusText;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal; 
end;

end;
```

Comment: Format your code properly and you'll find what is wrong ;-)

Comment: I a newbie to inno with less than 4 hours experience. I thought it would be something obvious DX

Comment: This is more about code sense than programming (you could apply this to any programming language, no matter if it uses curly braces, or `begin..end` blocks). This looks like some quick copy paste attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to use the below answer and tweaked it a bit to fix the invalid number or parameters message:

```
Source: "C:\Users\James\Downloads\DotNet Framework 4.5.1.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}; Check: FrameworkIsNotInstalled;
Source: "C:\Users\James\Downloads\adb-setup-1.4.2.exe"; DestDir: {tmp} ; Check: ADBNotInstalled;
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[code]
//check if .net 4.5 installed
function FrameworkIsNotInstalled: Boolean;
begin
    Result := not RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v4.0\Release');
end;
//install .net
procedure InstallFramework;
var
  StatusText: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  StatusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing .NET framework This may take a while...';
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
  try
    if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe'), '/p /noreboot', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
      MsgBox('.NET installation failed with code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) + '.',
        mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  finally
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusText;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal;
  end;
 end;
//check if adb is installed check is with setup installer
function ADBNotInstalled: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not DirExists(ExpandConstant('{sd}\adb'));
end;
procedure InstallADB;
var
  StatusText: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  StatusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing ADB this will be just a second...';
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
  try
    if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\adb-setup-1.4.2.exe'), '/q /noreboot', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
      MsgBox('ADB Failed to install with code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) + '.',
        mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  finally
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusText;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal;
  end;
 end;
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `end` keywords for a couple of times.

```
function FrameworkIsNotInstalled: Boolean; 
begin
  Result := not RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v4.0');
end;

procedure InstallFramework;
var
  StatusText: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  StatusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing .NET framework...';
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
  try
    if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe'), '/p /noreboot', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
      MsgBox('.NET installation failed with code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) + '.',
        mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  finally
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusText;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal;
  end;
end; // you forgot this

function isADBinstalled: Boolean; //error occurs on this line
begin
  Result := not DirExists(ExpandConstant '{sd}\adb');
end; // you forgot this  

procedure installadb; // you forgot the semicolon
var
  StatusText: string;
begin
  StatusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing ADB this shouldnt be long...';
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
  try
    if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\adb-setup-1.4.2.exe'), '/p /noreboot', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
      MsgBox('ADB Install failed with code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) + '.',
        mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  finally
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusText;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal; 
  end; // you forgot this 
end;
```

You can avoid those mistakes by formatting your code properly. Everytime you type `begin` you should directly type the corresponding `end`. Do the same for brackets and quotes.

Comment: Now I'm getting invalid number of parameters error and its on the line with the path I am checking...